# How can a NuGet package include transformations for both app.config and web.config?

Tags: web-config, app-config, transform, nuget

I'm trying to create a nuget package which will both add a DLL and configure it inside of the proper configuration file.  The package can be used in either a console/form application or a web application, so I want to update the appropriate configuration file, either app.config or web.config.

My files section in the .nuspec file contains the following inside of the  section.

```
    <file src="config.transform" target="content\app.config.transform"/>
    <file src="config.transform" target="content\web.config.transform"/>
```

The .nupkg file does contain both of the transforms inside of the content folder.

When I add my package to a project in VS2010 through Manage NuGet Packages, the only file which is ever modified is the app.config file.  Web.config is never touched.  In fact, in a web application with an existing web config, NuGet will create an app.config file which contains the modifications.

Is there a way of doing what I'm trying to do (and if so, how)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [a related bug report](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2550), it should already work how you want it to.  Are you running the latest version of NuGet?

Comment: This was totally my own fault.  What I did not realize is that NuGet is apparently smarter than I am, and will only apply web.config updates in a web project.  I had created a dll project and put both app.config and web.config in it to test my conversions.